# Change styles of component when hovering sibling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple case where I want the box2 to change background to yellow, if the box1 was hovered.

code sample:

```
const Box = styled.div`
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
`;

const Box2 = styled.div`
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 20px;

  ${Box}:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
`;

in render:
  <Box>Box 1</Box>
  <Box2>Box 2</Box2>
```

Link to the code preview:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvhgov

Thanks!

**Edit** This one above doesnt seem to work, dont know why, it should work?

Answer (score 5):

Depend on your render items you can do it with different approaches but as things we got here, you can use [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (+) or [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (~). So all you have to do is to replace this

```css
${Box}:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

with

```css
/* If you want to only select the next element sibling, you should replace ~ with + */

${Box}:hover ~ & { 
  background: yellow
}
```

**Working Demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-next-sibling

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';

const Box = styled.div`
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
`;

const Box2 = styled.div`
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 20px;
  ${props => props.hovered && css`
    background: yellow;
  `} 
`;

export default function App() {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {'' + hovered}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Box onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}>Box 1</Box>
      <Box2 hovered={hovered}>Box 2</Box2>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

With this approach, it doesn't matter are elements/components siblings or not. It will work for siblings but also when components are nested in different subtrees.